# Passing results of @BeforeAll to all of feature files executed in @Test or including in execution context

Tags: karate

We have setup a @BeforeAll method in a test Runner, which completes various pre-condition steps, before our tests should be ran, such as setting enum variables, response schemas, login authentication, and such.  This all runs fine and without issue.

However, when it moves to execute the tests, under the testParallel, Runner.path(feature list), these tests always get skipped.

```
19:22:56.411 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate.Runner - karate.env is: 'dev'
19:22:56.744 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.Suite - [config] classpath:karate-config.js
19:22:56.755 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate.Suite - backed up existing 'target/karate-reports' dir to: target/karate-reports_1699060976753
19:22:56.756 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.Suite - waiting for 2 features to complete
Karate version: 1.4.1 | env: dev
======================================================
elapsed:   0.35 | threads:   16 | thread time: 0.00 
features:     0 | skipped:    2 | efficiency: 0.00
scenarios:    0 | passed:     0 | failed: 0
======================================================
```

1. Is it possible to not call the config within the runner, since it is set as true in the `Runner.runFeature("classpath:net/charter/" + serviceName + "/constants.feature", args, true);` line of the @BeforeAll?  This is not an issue, just an ask.
2. Is it possible to pass the results from the @BeforeAll method to the @Test method without coding each value individually, as these change between services?
3. Is it possible to also pass these values, such as the auth token, env, and baseurl values to the @AfterAll call
4. Is the only way to get output in any feature ran within @BeforeAll to use print statements rather than `karate.logger.debug('enumList is:  ', enumList);` as logger does not appear to provide any output.

Background:

- Our config does the following for all services - determines environment, setup db connections, setups urls, setups up global variables used in headers
- Our @BeforeAll call completes calls that are needed just for the service to execute, such as authentication based on user values sent in, sets enums for comparisons (used in numerous places), sets response schemas for each endpoint (used to compare results in use of the endpoint), makes other pre-req calls that may be needed, such as getting user list, addresses, billing info, and such

Answer (score 0):

Your question on sharing state between `@BeforeAll` and `@Test` is a Java / JUnit specific question and not related to Karate. One possible option is to use a Java singleton, initialize it in `@BeforeAll` and then in your Karate tests (or karate-config.js) you can access this singleton for e.g.

```
* def Utils = Java.type('my.Utils`)
# the java getConfig() returns a Map
* def myConfig = Utils.getInstance().getConfig()
```

`Runner.runFeature()` is not really recommended for running Karate tests. I would have thought `karate.callSingle()` naturally solves what you seem to be trying to do here. Any other asks require changes to Karate, and possibly this feature-request (which very few teams seem to want) would make a difference: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2235

Comment: We currently use callonce and call single but run into the multi thread issue - `org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: Multi threaded access requested by thread Thread[pool-2-thread-8,5,main] but is not allowed for language(s) js.` so simply exploring work arounds to resolve this issue in order to get a clean run rather than having to test twice and hope the same tests do not fail for the threading access to our setup calls.

Comment: @mike the concurrency issue has a long history - you can start digging here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2329 - as of now, no other team has reported this problem with 1.4.1 - IMO it is quite clear that your team is mis-using karate.callSingle() or using non-thread safe JS code. there is only one way to make progress - which is for your team to submit a way to replicate. if it means half a day taking your project and removing bits until you still see the problem - IMHO I think it is worth the effort. until then this is not considered an issue with karate

Comment: Will work on sample project, but multi-thread issue is still happening `* def headers = karate.callSingle('classpath:adapters/authentication.feature?' + username)
js failed:
>>>>
01: karate.callSingle('classpath:adapters/authentication.feature?' + username)
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: Multi threaded access requested by thread Thread[pool-2-thread-7,5,main] but is not allowed for language(s) js.`